# Extracting XML nodes based on conditions in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am working on a project where I have two little tables that store XML value. My requirement is to pull out columns based on conditions.

1. I have a variable tempvar. When tempvar = 'H', I want all the nodes from both the tables to show up in XML fashion
2. When tempvar = 'P', I want all the nodes from the first table and only one node from the second table to show up in XML fashion

Rexter link: http://rextester.com/BSRX9069

I have only created the temp tables. And included desired output for each condition in the rexter.

No clue where to start. Any help?

Comment: Hey Rick, pictures of code = evil, can you copy and paste it so we can copy and paste it.

Comment: @HolmesIV haha ok will do in a min

Comment: question edited. New rexter linjk. Pls chk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I got this correctly:

```sql
create table #temp1(xml_data xml)
insert into #temp1
select 
xml_data = 
(select 
     cid = '1001',
     name = 'tim',
     age = '15',
     req = '1',
     part = '1'
 for xml path(''),type)

create table #temp2(xml_data xml)
insert into #temp2
select 
xml_data = 
(select 
     cid = '1001',
     education = '5',
     resi = 'Yes',
     active = '1'
 for xml path(''),type);
```

--Declare your variable

```sql
DECLARE @YourVar CHAR(1)='H';
```

--XML will omit any values which are NULL. The `CASE` in the final `SELECT` will set all not wanted values to NULL. The effect: They will not show up in the final XML:

```sql
WITH t1 AS
(
    SELECT xml_data.value(N'(cid/text())[1]',N'int') AS cid
          ,xml_data.value(N'(name/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS [name]
          ,xml_data.value(N'(age/text())[1]',N'int') AS age
          ,xml_data.value(N'(req/text())[1]',N'int') AS req
          ,xml_data.value(N'(part/text())[1]',N'int') AS part
    FROM #temp1
)
,t2 AS
(
    SELECT xml_data.value(N'(cid/text())[1]',N'int') AS cid
          ,xml_data.value(N'(education/text())[1]',N'int') AS education
          ,xml_data.value(N'(resi/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS resi
          ,xml_data.value(N'(active/text())[1]',N'int') AS active
    FROM #temp2
)
SELECT t1.*
      ,CASE WHEN @YourVar='H' THEN t2.education END AS education
      ,CASE WHEN @YourVar='H' THEN t2.resi END AS resi
      ,CASE WHEN @YourVar='H' THEN t2.active END AS active
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.cid=t2.cid
FOR XML PATH('root');

--clean-up
go
drop table #temp1, #temp2
```